# Unit Test Angularjs directive, which contains private timeout, with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, timeout

I have a directive, which should behave differently, depending on how much time passed since it's initialization:

```
am.directive('showText', () => ({
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  scope: {
    value: '@'
  },
  controller: ($scope, $timeout) => {
    console.log('timeout triggered');

    $scope.textVisible = false;

    let visibilityCheckTimeout = $timeout(() => {
      if (parseInt($scope.value, 10) < 100) {
        $scope.textVisible = true;
      }
    }, 330);

    // Clear timeout upon directive destruction
    $scope.$on('$destroy', $timeout.cancel(visibilityCheckTimeout));
  },
}));
```

The problem is, that when I'm trying to test it with Jasmine, I can't seem to find a way to trigger this timeout in any way. Already tried a `$timeout.flush()` and `$timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks()` (which actually throws an error, if I'll comment `flush` call). But it's still not triggering that timeout's callback execution

```
describe('showText.', () => {
  let $compile;
  let $rootScope;
  let $scope;
  let $timeout;

  const compileElement = (rootScope, value = 0) => {
    $scope = rootScope.$new();
    $scope.value = value;

    const element = $compile(`
      <show-text
        value="value"
      ></show-text>
    `)($scope);

    $scope.$digest();

    return element;
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    module('app.directives.showText');

    inject((_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$timeout_) => {
      $compile = _$compile_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      $timeout = _$timeout_;
    });
  });

  it(`Process lasts > 0.33s. Should show text.`, () => {
    const VALUE = 30;
    const element = compileElement($rootScope, VALUE);
    const elementContent = element.find('.show-text__content');

    $timeout.flush(1000);

    $timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks();

    $rootScope.$digest();

    expect(element.isolateScope().textVisible).toBeTruthy();
    expect(elementContent.length).toEqual(1);
    expect(elementContent.text().trim()).toBe('Example text');
  });
});
```

Test fails.

Can't find what am I doing wrong. Any tips on how to properly test such a case?

Thanks.

**UPD**
After some investigation, I've found that in this particular test-case, in `compileElement` function, `value` property isn't being evaluated by `$compile` service. And equals `"value"`. I've used same function already 10th of times, and can't get, why it's not taking a `$scope.value`'s property as it was before.

Comment: How do you know that timeout wasn't run, have you checked it with breakpoint?

Comment: @estus With breakpoint, as well as putting a console log inside of it. Also was removing this "if" statement and checking if property `textVisible` changes. Usually when putting `console.log`s inside, they give an output between test cases in terminal. Currently trying to expose timeout's callback using $scope, and spy on it.

Comment: @estus added an "update" to question. Seems like, for some reason, passed value isn't evaluated by `$compile` service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this happens is that `$timeout.cancel(visibilityCheckTimeout)` launches unconditionally and immediately. Instead, it should be

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', () => $timeout.cancel(visibilityCheckTimeout));
```

There are things that can be done to improve testability (besides the fact that `$timeout` works here as one-time scope watcher and asks to be replaced with the one).

`$timeout` can be successfully [spied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37220166/3731501):

```
beforeEach(module('app', ($provide) => {
  $provide.decorator('$timeout', ($delegate) => {
    var timeoutSpy = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue($delegate);
    angular.extend(timeoutSpy, $delegate);
    spyOn(timeoutSpy, 'cancel').and.callThrough();
    return timeoutSpy;
  });
}));
```

Private `$timeout` callback can be exposed to scope.

```
$scope._visibilityCheckHandler = () => {
  if (parseInt($scope.value, 10) < 100) {
    $scope.textVisible = true;
  }
};
$timeout($scope._visibilityCheckHandler, 330);
```

This way all of the calls can be spied and get full coverage:

```
let directiveScope;
...

const element = $compile(`...`)($scope);

directiveScope = element.isolateScope();
spyOn(directiveScope, '_visibilityCheckHandler').and.callThrough();

$scope.$digest();
...

expect($timeout).toHaveBeenCalledWith(directiveScope._visibilityCheckHandler, 330);
expect($timeout.cancel).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

In this case here's no need to have separate specs for '>= 0.33s' and '< 0.33s' with `flush` delay argument, `$timeout`'s inner work was already tested in Angular specs. Also, callback logic can be tested separately from `$timeout` spec.

Comment: Revised a way I'm testing those kind of stuff, and taken approach, you suggested. Thanks