# How to mock $timeout service using sinon?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, sinon

I need to create unit test for a method in Angular controller that utilizes $timeout service. The problem is that I was told not to use inject. So I have to mock $timeout myself. How can I do it using sinon?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525588/unit-test-angularjs-directive-which-contains-private-timeout-with-jasmine . The same applies to Mocha/Sinon. It is not clear what *not to use inject* should mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a simple replacement of $timeout:

```
const $timeout = (func) => {
    func();
};
```

which I pass to controller