# Test a directive function through watch

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-mock

I have a function in angular directive that gets triggered on watch. How do i test the timeout based scrolling activity of the function `scroll` since its not in scope?

```
scope.$watch('elementId', function(value) {
    //How do i test scroll function contents?
    scroll(element, value);
});

function scroll (pE, element) {
   console.log('Here');
   $timeout(function afterTimeout () {
     var scrollTo = $('#' + element);
     var container = $(pE);
     container.animate({scrollTop : scrollTo[0].offsetTop - container[0].offsetTop - 10}, 'slow');
   }, 250);
}
```

The detailed code is here
http://jsfiddle.net/QGmCF/68/

Comment: Unit-testing a real DOM isn't very pleasing task. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37527210/3731501 on how to test $timeout calls. Since it is not in scope, you already know that it would be easier to test if it were on scope. Expose `scroll` function as scope/controller method, this will benefit testability.

Comment: Ah okay..will take a look at that.thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few suggestions to clean up your code.  The first thing to realize is that you should be injecting the mock `$timeout` object into your test and calling `$timeout.flush(251)` to make sure your code runs.

Like this:

```
it('test watch', inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $timeout) {
    // as before
    $timeout.flush(251);
    // test that your code has run
}));
```

Another suggestion: instead of using jQuery's `$` object, use `$window.document` or `$document[0]` to access the browser's native components.  With this, you can write this:

```
var scrollTo = $document[0].getElementById(element);
```

and then you no longer have to access your `scrollTo` element with `[0]`.