# How to unit test / mock a $timeout call?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking, spyon

How do I mock the timeout call, here?

```
$scope.submitRequest = function () {

    var formData = getData();

    $scope.form = JSON.parse(formData);

    $timeout(function () {
        $('#submitForm').click();            
    }, 2000);

};
```

I want to see timeout has been called with the correct function.

I would like an example of the spyon function mocking $timeout.

```
spyOn(someObject,'$timeout')
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, DOM manipulation should only be performed in directives.
Also, it's better to use angular.element(...), than $(...).
Finally, to do this, you can expose your element's click handler to the scope, spy on it, and check if that handler has been called:

```
$timeout.flush(2000);
$timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks();
expect(scope.myClickHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

EDIT:

since that's a form and there is no ng-click handler, you can use ng-submit handler, or add a name to your form and do:

```
$timeout.flush(2000);
$timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks();
expect(scope.formName.$submitted).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: It is form being submitted, there is no click handler.  I suppose I could had a click handler, but that's kind of ugly.

Answer (score 4):

`$timeout` can be spied or mocked as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37220166/3731501):

```
beforeEach(module('app', ($provide) => {
  $provide.decorator('$timeout', ($delegate) => {
    var timeoutSpy = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue($delegate);
    // methods aren't copied automatically to spy
    return angular.extend(timeoutSpy, $delegate);
  });
}));
```

There's not much to test here, since `$timeout` is called with anonymous function. For testability reasons it makes sense to expose it as scope/controller method:

```
$scope.submitFormHandler = function () {
    $('#submitForm').click();            
};

...
$timeout($scope.submitFormHandler, 2000);
```

Then spied `$timeout` can be tested:

```
$timeout.and.stub(); // in case we want to test submitFormHandler separately
scope.submitRequest();
expect($timeout).toHaveBeenCalledWith(scope.submitFormHandler, 2000);
```

And the logic inside `$scope.submitFormHandler` can be tested in different test.

Another problem here is that jQuery doesn't work well with unit tests and requires to be tested against real DOM (this is one of many reasons why jQuery should be avoided in AngularJS applications when possible). It's possible to spy/mock jQuery API like shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36356692/3731501).

`$(...)` call can be spied with:

```
var init = jQuery.prototype.init.bind(jQuery.prototype);
spyOn(jQuery.prototype, 'init').and.callFake(init);
```

And can be mocked with:

```
var clickSpy = jasmine.createSpy('click');
spyOn(jQuery.prototype, 'init').and.returnValue({ click: clickSpy });
```

Notice that it's expected that mocked function will return jQuery object for chaining with `click` method.

When `$(...)` is mocked, the test doesn't require `#submitForm` fixture to be created in DOM, this is the preferred way for isolated unit test.

Answer (score 1):

Create mock for $timeout provider:

```
var f = () => {} 
var myTimeoutProviderMock = () => f;
```

Use it:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myModule', ($provide) => {
  $provide.factory('$timeout', myTimeoutProviderMock);
}))
```

Now you can test:

```
spyOn(f);
expect(f).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

P.S. you'd better test result of function in timeout.

Comment: `spyOn(f)` won't work. `myTimeoutProviderMock` will keep using original `f`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that piece of code is within the controller or being created in the test by $controller, then $timeout can be passed in the construction parameter.  So you could just do something like:

```
var timeoutStub = sinon.stub();
var myController = $controller('controllerName', timeoutStub);
$scope.submitRequest();
expect(timeoutStub).to.have.been.called;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unit Tesitng $timeout with flush delay

You have to flush the queue of the $timeout service by calling $timeout.flush()

```
describe('controller: myController', function(){
describe('showAlert', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        // Arrange
        vm.alertVisible = false;

        // Act
        vm.showAlert('test alert message');
    });

    it('should show the alert', function(){
        // Assert
        assert.isTrue(vm.alertVisible);
    });

    it('should hide the alert after 5 seconds', function(){
        // Act - flush $timeout queue to fire off deferred function
        $timeout.flush();

        // Assert
        assert.isFalse(vm.alertVisible);
    });
  })
});
```

Please checkout this link http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/03/06/angularjs-unit-testing-code-that-uses-timeout

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with [Frane Poljak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630623/frane-poljak)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49500845/2314242). You should surely follow his way. Second way to do it is by mocking $timeout service like below:

```
describe('MainController', function() {
var $scope, $timeout;

beforeEach(module('app'));

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $injector) {
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  $timeout = jasmine.createSpy('$timeout');
  $controller('MainController', {
    $scope: $scope,
    $timeout: $timeout
  });
}));

it('should submit request', function() {
  $scope.submitRequest();
  expect($timeout).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Here is the plunker having both approaches: http://plnkr.co/edit/s5ls11

Comment: I would not recommend this approach. `$timeout` is already part of the ngMock module

Comment: Agreed, this approach is not recommended as ngMock decorate `$timeout` service with flush and verifyNoPendingTasks so they are encouraged. It's just a possibility.